# Android action bar tabs

Tags: user-interface, android-actionbar, android-tabs, action-bar-navigation

Currently I'm working with action bar tabs they are shown perfectly with 4.1 device but when i run on same screen size in lower version 4.0 then the action bar tabs are shown as "ActionBar spinner navigation"

[image]

I want them to be shown like this one:

[image]

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser == null) {

        navigateToLogin();
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, currentUser.getUsername());
    }

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);



    mSectionPargerAdapter = new SectionPargerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionPargerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            for (int i = 0; i < mSectionPargerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
                // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
                // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
                // this tab is selected.
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText( mSectionPargerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(MainActivity.this));}
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is optimization done by system.  The second view is called stacked action bar and first is called action bar with spinner.  You can achieve what you want by first adding all tabs and then setting the mode of action bar as

```
setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)
```